# Analog of isInEditMode for @Preview in JetpackCompose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I am developing an app using Jetpack compose and have a problem with fonts import during Jetpack preview. Preview is empty and show an error (Render problem):

```
Font resource ID #0x... cannot be retrieved
```

In custom view for example we have a

```
isInEditMode
```

to control layout preview in design section and we are able to disable some logic that ruins preview.

Is any way to do it for Jetpack @Preview ?
I currently read all available docs/articles and didn't found the answer.

Would be very appreciate for any info.

The Jetpack Compose code is:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenContent() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(50))
            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.search_field_background_color)),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Icon(
            painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_search_image), contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.search_screen_magnifier_icon_content_description)
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp),
            text = stringResource(R.string.search_screen_search_field_text),
            fontSize = 12.sp,
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.search_field_text_color),
            fontFamily = getFont(R.font.nunito_sans_extra_bold)
        )
    }
}

//according to the plan this method will contain
//some flag to return null in @Preview mode
@Composable
private fun getFont(@FontRes fontId : Int): FontFamily? {
    return FontFamily(ResourcesCompat.getFont(LocalContext.current, fontId)!!)
}

@Preview(showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    ScreenContent()
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Compose has its own local composition value for this case, which is [`LocalInspectionMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#LocalInspectionMode()). You can use it like this:

```
@Composable
private fun getFont(@FontRes fontId : Int): FontFamily? {
    if (LocalInspectionMode.current) return null
    return FontFamily(ResourcesCompat.getFont(LocalContext.current, fontId)!!)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I also have not been able to find an out of the box solution, but I have come up with an alternative. We can take advantage of local composition. This is my attempt at addressing this:

```
val LocalPreviewMode = compositionLocalOf { false }

@Composable
fun MyView() {
    if (LocalPreviewMode.current) {
        // render in preview mode
    } else {
        // render normally 
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewMyView() {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalPreviewMode provides true) {
        MyView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with following condition

```
if (LocalInspectionMode.current) {
    // Place your edit mode composables here
} else {
    // Place your actual composables here
}
```

Your updated code can use it like this.

```
@Composable
fun ScreenContent() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(50)),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        if (LocalInspectionMode.current){
            // Place your edit mode composables here
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp),
                text = "Search",
            )
        }else {
            // Place your actual composables here
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp),
                text = "Search",
                fontFamily = getFont(R.font.nunito_sans_extra_bold)
            )
        }
    }
}

//according to the plan this method will contain
//some flag to return null in @Preview mode
@Composable
private fun getFont(@FontRes fontId : Int): FontFamily {
    return FontFamily(ResourcesCompat.getFont(LocalContext.current, fontId)!!)
}

@Preview(showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    ScreenContent()
}
```