# Passing Application to ViewModel in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following inside a `@composable` function. I am getting an error with the previews. I am not sure this works on a device either.

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val noteTrainerViewModel = NoteTrainerViewModel(context.applicationContext as Application)
```

And here is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to class android.app.Application
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because in preview there's no `Application` running. You cannot use methods that depend on `Application` during preview

On a real run this code will work fine

Comment: what is the workaround for this, since I am not able to see the preview of my composable and I can't work on UI

Comment: @Notron check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70163730/3585796) on how to check if composable is run from preview